# XAML designer not loading - universal windows platform VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I am getting this error when I try to load one of my working project in VS2015. I tried reinstalling the SDK as well but still not working. The app is running fine on debug mode but the UI designer not loading. how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to open your project with VS 2017 ? Personally I had the same problem and I ended up abandoned vs2015 to vs2017 which is more stable than its predecessor version

Comment: I did, vs2017 not even loading the project even though I have the SDK installed

Comment: What is your os version ? What is your project type ? Did you try to creat a blank page ?

Comment: 1. Win 10 
2. Win 8.1 
3. yes, that too has same issue

Comment: Please open your Control Panel and open Programs and Features ,in the list of installed programs, select Windows Software Development Kit  and select Repair.

Comment: I did this but unfortunately this also did not work. I ended up rolling back my last windows update and it fixed the issue. It looks the issue was related to win10 update (It might not sound related but this actually fixed the issue).

Comment: glad to hear that, I advise you to open a ticket with microsoft for this problem to be solved definitively